# Why d we need child exit after execvp?

Tags: c, exit, execvp

I have been recently wondering why do we need to use exit after the execution of a child after performing execvp. An in depth explannation is welcome.

Comment: `execvp` does not return on success, so there is no "after". On error it might be wise to exit (or not. Depends on the program logic)

Comment: What is your evidence that this is needed?  And in depth explanation is welcome.

Comment: If `exec*` returns, it is because of an error.   Often, a reasonable reaction is to print an error message and terminate.

Comment: I am getting to code using UNIX and recently I got told to always use exit after executing a child. I did not get the chance to ask further yet I want to understand why.

Comment: I hope whoever told you that also said to use `_exit()` (assuming a POSIX system) and not `exit()`.  `_exit()` won't do things like flush IO buffers inherited from the parent process to the files the parent is writing to.

Comment: that is really useful thank you for telling me!

Answer (score 1):

You do not *need* for the child to call `exit()` after `execvp()`, but it is often wise for you to ensure that it does so.  So much so as to support giving that to novices as a rule.

When a call to `execvp()` or one of the other exec functions succeeds, it has the effect of replacing the currently-running process image with a new one.  As a result, these functions do not return on success, and nothing that follows matters in that case.  The issue, then, is entirely about what to do in the event that the `exec*` call *fails*.

If you do not exit the child in the event that an exec fails then it will continue running the code of the parent.  That is rarely intended or wanted.  It may do work that it was not intended to do, delay the parent (that is often `wait()`ing for it) by not exiting promptly, and eventually mislead the parent with an exit status that is not reflective of what actually happened.

All of that, and perhaps more, is addressed by ensuring that the control flow following an `exec*` call pretty quickly reaches program termination with a failure status (typically via `_Exit()` or `_exit()`; less typically via `exit()` or `abort()`).  Depending on the circumstances, it may or may not be appropriate to emit a diagnostic message before exiting, or to perform some other kind of cleanup.